# QQmlListProperty converted to opaque QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm having an issue with QQmlListProperty.

My class returns a QQmlListProperty list. I call a function in qml of a c++ class which returns the corresponding list.
But when I try to access the list, like, *list.lenght* i get an undefined javascript object.

***C++ SIDE***

```
class IControllerInterface {
...
public:
    QQmlListProperty<IObject> objectsQml() {
        return QQmlListProperty<IObject>(this,
                                         this,
                                         &IController::qmlListAppend,
                                         &IController::qmlListCount,
                                         &IController::qmlListAt,
                                         &IController::qmlListClear);
    }

    private:
        static void qmlListAppend(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list, IObject *object);
        static IObject *qmlListAt(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list, int index);
        static int qmlListCount(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list);
        static void qmlListClear(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list);
...
}

void IController::qmlListAppend(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list, IObject *object)
{

}

IObject *IController::qmlListAt(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list, int index)
{
    return reinterpret_cast< IController* >(list->data)->objects()[index];
}

int IController::qmlListCount(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list)
{
    return reinterpret_cast< IController* >(list->data)->objects().size();
}

void IController::qmlListClear(QQmlListProperty<IObject> *list)
{

}
```

...

```
class RestAPI {

...

    Q_INVOKABLE QQmlListProperty<IObject> lookupObjectsQml(const IObject::ObjectType type) {
        Q_D(RestAPI);
        return d->getController(type)->objectsQml();
    }

...

}
```

*Note: RestAPI is a singleton class

***QML SIDE***

```
RestControl {
        id: ctrl

        Component.onCompleted: {
            var lst = RestAPI.lookupObjectsQml(IObject.FARM)
            console.log(lst)
            console.log('found ' + lst.length + ' objects..')
            for(var obj in lst) {
                console.log(obj.id)
            }
        }
}
```

When I call ***RestAPI.lookupObjectsQml(IObject.FARM)*** and assign the result to the variable ***lst***.. I receive an opaque qvariant object:

QVariant(QQmlListProperty)

This way I cannot acess my IObjects*.

For example, this call will return undefined: *lst.length*

What I'm doing wrong?

> DEBUG 05-01-19 10:42:49:889 [GUI] [root] QVariant(QQmlListProperty)
>
> DEBUG 05-01-19 10:42:49:890 [GUI] [root] found undefined objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `QQmlListProperty` supposed to be exposed to QML as a property itself:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<IObject> objects READ objects)
```

And in order to use this type correctly the semantics of JavaScript in your QML code should be like:

```
RestAPI.lookupObjectsQml(IObject.FARM);
for(var obj in RestAPI.objects) {
   console.log(obj.id)
}
```

The rest of your code is showing you will be able to accomplish such change with C++. But of course you could find a number of other ways [for [instance]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) to provide the list of objects from the function call as you wanted but not this way when QQmlListProperty is used exactly as QML property.

Comment: A few hours ago, before you answer, I did exactly as you just answered in here, and, indeed it worked flawless.
I was expecting I could have a QQmlListProperty as a returning argument from a Q_INVOKABLE function, but it's not supported by QML engine apparently.. sad!

Comment: I would've loved to upvote this answer... this is how QQmlListProperty *usually* works. But clearly there is more to it, as I have a QQmlListProperty exposed using Q_PROPERTY which I still cannot access, and renders as a opaque QVariant. I even add to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE on the QQmlListProperty<MyClass> type to avoid warnings about the type being unknown. Doesn't make any sense to me, I've never seen anything of the sort before.